# java jar writes in two different character-encoding

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, character-encoding, arabic

So my code is working fine when running from Eclipse, but executing the project's runnable jar does not.

Here is my code:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class cc {

    public static HttpURLConnection con;
    public static String url = "http://bac.onec.dz/index.php";
    public static int begin;
    public static int max;
    public static boolean paused=false;
    public static String path="result.csv";

    public static void setData(int b,int m){
        begin=b;max=m;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {
            int i =1;
            setData(35043487,2);
            while (i<=max && !paused) {
            sendPost(begin++);
            i++;
        }
    }

    private static void sendPost(int mat) throws Exception {
        String urlParameters ;
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        BufferedReader in;
        StringBuffer response;

        con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Host", "bac.onec.dz");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        con.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://bac.onec.dz/");
        con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb=ANNCLHAEAAAAAAAAJHKBHDAAAAAAAAAAEADAOFFHFHFHAAAADAAANKIFFKIFAAAA; TS1ff960=20859ee226968392c837af0430f21cf0087e23d48701410f5785a62879b49ee6533a75145e5dca68b041d236; aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=GAABBCCHICBGBAAECAAAAAKCHHAAAAAAEACAALAAKGFHAAAADAAAAGAACKIFAAAA");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        urlParameters = "matriculebac="+mat+"&dobac=%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%B8%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%B1+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D8%AA%D9%8A%D8%AC%D8%A9";

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
         in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
         response = new StringBuffer();     
         Object[] aa = in.lines().toArray();

        for (Object object : aa) response.append(object.toString()+"\n");
        in.close();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("alert\\(.*?\\);");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(response.toString());
        String[] person = null;
         if (matcher.find())
        {
            String p =matcher.group(0).substring(7, matcher.group(0).length()-3);
            person = p.split("\\\\n");
        }
         try {
            String [] pp= 
                 {
                     person[0 ],
                     person[1 ].split(":")[1].substring(1),
                     person[2 ].split(":")[1].substring(1),
                     person[10].split(":")[1].substring(1),
                     person[4 ].split(":")[1].substring(1),
                     person[5 ].split(":")[1].substring(1),
                     person[6 ].split(":")[1].substring(1),
                     person[7 ].split(":")[1].substring(1),

                };

             CvsWrite(pp);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    public static  void CvsWrite(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> pers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String string : args) pers.add(string);
        String clct1 = pers.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")) + "\r\n";
        File f = new File(path);
        if (!f.exists())  
            try {   
                f.createNewFile();
                List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
                test.add("الملاحظة");
                test.add("رقم التسجيل");
                test.add("الشعبة");
                test.add("المعدل");
                test.add("اللقب");
                test.add("الاسم");
                test.add("مكان الميلاد");
                test.add("تاريخ الميلاد");
                String clct2 = test.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","))+ "\r\n\r\n";
                Files.write(Paths.get(path),clct2.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

        } catch (IOException e) {}


        Files.write(Paths.get(path),clct1.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    }

}
```

Running from eclipse, the output file is perfect with UTF-8 encoding.

Running from exported jar, a part of the output file is in ANSI encoding. Now that wouldn't be a problem if I'm writing just these words, but the code writes other content in Arabic, and the output be like

Output file was opened with Notepad++
in ANSI 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RGEj.png
in UTF-8
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li0qf.png

As I mentioned this problem hasn't encountered when running from eclipse

Comment: I've tidied up the formatting a bit, but I believe your sample output is the wrong way round - you've specified the *correct* output is "in ANSI" and the broken output is "in UTF-8". I suggest you edit your question to reverse this, if you actually meant it the other way round.

Comment: No, the sample is one output with two lines, first line is in ANSI, the second is in UTF-8

Comment: Well that's *not* the output from the code you've provided, and it wouldn't make sense that way round, as no ANSI encoding that I'm aware of can actually handle Arabic. ("ANSI" isn't a single fixed encoding. It's a whole set of them.) It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve] with sample output, rather than *part* of your code.

Comment: Thank you, I'll make some modifications in the question

Comment: This still isn't a [mcve]. We should be able to copy, paste, compile, run, and see the same result that you do.

Comment: It doesn't help that you haven't told us what tool is autodetecting the encoding as "ANSI" (which as I've said, isn't a single encoding). Additionally, your file clearly includes more data than the data you're writing in this program... my guess is that the problem isn't in the code you've got here, it's in whatever wrote the *first* part of the file.

Comment: I opened it with Notepad++, SublimeText, MS Notepad, all results are the same

Comment: Your example program is now far from short - but the fact that you're creating an `InputStreamReader` without specifying the encoding is another problem. What's the *actual* data you're reading from the web?

Comment: Basically, I think you need to look more carefully at each part of your program - I think you've got bigger problems than just writing out the file, but until you look at individual parts, we can't easily help you. (A short but complete program which *only* concerned itself with writing out the data wouldn't need to make any web requests.)

Comment: It's an HTTP post request response. The response is text/html, i took the part that i want from it then write to the file, after writing the description head line.

Comment: Yes I verified every bit. As the question says i think the problem is in the jar execution.

Comment: Well, the problem is the way you're using the platform default encoding in two places. That's not the fault of "jar execution" - it's a bug in your code. And "text/html" is a content type, not an encoding.

Comment: Yes i surely know the difference between encoding and content type, but this bug is tricky since I did what you told me to (specifying the encoding in the two places), that did not work, but specifying only the header line worked just fine :)

Comment: If you know the difference between an encoding and a content type, why did you tell me the *content type* when it's the encoding that's important? I'm afraid I'm done here - I've explained why you've got problems, and that you really need to look at each individual part of your program more carefully... I don't think I can help any more until you've done that.

Comment: Yes Sir, that's probably a result of our crappy education system.So thank you a lot,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that just sounds like you're getting different default encodings when running in different ways - which is somewhat to be expected.

Just specify the encoding when you convert the text to binary:

```
byte[] bytes = col.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Files.write(Paths.get(path), bytes, StandardOpenOption.Append);
```

(I would have suggested using `Files.write` and passing in the text directly, but that will use the platform-default line break, which would be a separate issue...)

You've got the same problem when creating an `InputStreamReader`:

```
in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```

That's assuming that the data is in the platform-default encoding. *Never assume that*. You should find out what the *actual* encoding of the data is, and use that to read. Then decide (as a separate matter) what encoding you want to write in.

Comment: @Bil: Hopefully when you've made the question clearer, we'll be able to sort it out. But you should definitely specify the encoding you want *every* time you convert text into binary data.

Comment: Thank you sir, I will definitely take that into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Used was `String.getBytes()` which uses the default operating system encoding of the current machine. That is not portable. Specify the encoding.

As the existing old content was ANSI, continue with ANSI.

```
   Files.write(Paths.get(path), clct2.getBytes("Windows-1256"), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

And read the file with ANSI:

```
String s = new String(bytes, "Windows-1256");
```

Comment: If *at all possible*, it would be better to use UTF-8 consistently though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Totally agree (gave +1), but when appending be a lemming.

Comment: The first line must be shown correctly and that was with "ANSI." Unfortunately ANSI is a catch-all for any encoding. In the UTF-8 image one could read the hex codes of the Arabic letters. Maybe that helps in finding the correct encoding. Cp708, Cp720, Cp864, Cp10004, Cp20420 terrible. Maybe "correct" old files to the universal UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Using the default operating system encoding for the first and second file-writing operation, or specifying the same encoding for both, encountered the same problem which is encoding conflict. 
**The solution is:** to specify the encoding for the fist file-writing operation to UTF-8.

```
.
.
String clct2 = test.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","))+ "\r\n\r\n";
Files.write(Paths.get(path),clct2.getBytes("UTF-8"), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        } catch (IOException e) {}
Files.write(Paths.get(path),clct1.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
.
.
```

> This is certainly a dumb solution, since the bug is about portability and default OS encoding, but it worked :)